# Observer not getting called in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Can some one please point out the mistake in this observer example?
I have been googling and searching all the day but all in vain
Here is my code for the module in **magento\app\etc\modules** with the name of "Meteorify_Observerexample.xml".

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Meteorify_Observerexample>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Meteorify_Observerexample>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here is my code of "config.xml" in **magento\app\code\local\Meteorify\Observerexample\etc**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Meteorify_Observerexample>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Meteorify_Observerexample>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <meteorifyobserverexample>
                <class>Observerexample_Model</class>
            </meteorifyobserverexample>
        </models>


        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>example</method>
                    </Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
         </global>

</config>
```

Here is my code of "Observer.php" located in **magento\app\code\local\Meteorify\Observerexample\Model**

```
    <?php
class Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer {

    public function example($observer) {
        //$observer contains data passed from when the event was triggered.

        Mage::log($observer);

        Mage::log('We just made an Observer!');
        echo "The event has been captured";
    }

}
?>
```

I have also tried by deleting the cache and log the list of events being fired by adding the  Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true); in Mage.php file and the selected event is being fired from there.But the observer is not getting called for the given event.
Any hint or help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the mistake
It was in my my 'Observer.php'. I was logging the $observer object which was producing some error.Removing that line solved the problem.